# NFS export quota

Tags: linux, nfs, quota

I have two NFS export in **/etc/exports**

```
/export/ipcamera 192.168.1.0/24(rw,nohide,insecure,no_subtree_check,async)
/export/ipcamera2 192.168.1.0/24(rw,nohide,insecure,no_subtree_check,async)
```

Is there any easy way to set 50GB quota per export?

Comment: Yes, setup [quotas](http://www.debian-administration.org/article/47/Limiting_your_users_use_of_disk_space_with_quotas)

Comment: quotas are not set in the exports file. Usually they are managed by the underlying file system. Setting up quotas will depend on your filesystem.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to, don't know how or cant use quota stuff - You can create image files on your main storage for each cam.

64GB container ext3 or fat32, choose one.

```
 dd if=/dev/zero of=cam03.img bs=1M count=64000
 # mkfs ext3 -F cam03.img
 # mkfs fat32 -F cam03.img
```

Create a mount directory

```
mkdir /mnt/cam03
chown nobody:nogroup /mnt/cam03
```

Mount the image

```
 mount -o loop,rw,sync /mnt/MAIN/CCTV/cam03.img /mnt/cam03
```

You still have to deal with remounting the image on each boot and making sure NFS remounts too.

My MAIN are 4 2TB disks using ZFS, so I have good redundancy and fast read write. This worked pretty well for me.